# write down all the permutations of the set {1,2,3} using two-line notation

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups

So I was asked this on a practice set and I'm a bit confused. I know how two line notation works, but for permutations does this mean that the top row will always be (1 2 3)?

This is what I think the answer is but I'm not sure.

(1 2 3)   (1 2 3)   (1 2 3)   (1 2 3)   (1 2 3)  (1 2 3)

(1 2 3)   (2 1 3)   (3 1 2)   (1 3 2)   (3 2 1)  (2 3 1)

Comment: That is correct

Comment: usually written $\pmatrix{1&&2&&3\\1&&2&&3}$ etc.